# angular, css transitions, and changing class after transition

Tags: angular, css-animations, css-transitions

I have an element in my template that looks like this:

```
<div [ngClass]="isClosed ? 'closeDiv' : ''"></div>
```

On a click event I set `isClosed = true` and the template has the `closeDiv` class added.

This class triggers a CSS transition for 2000ms.

Now, once the transition is done, I also want to change the css `display` property.

What's the most angular-esque way to handle it? My initial idea:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'closeDiv' : isClosed, 'hideDiv' : isHidden}" >
```

and then in my onclick event function:

```
closeDiv(): void {
    this.isClosed  = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.isHidden = true;
    },2000)
}
```

and then my css for `.hideDiv` would set the display property to none.

...but...setTimeout always feels hacky. Is there a better way to handle this? Or is this an acceptable route to take?

Comment: You should use [Angular animations](https://angular.io/guide/animations) to handle this easily.

Comment: @YannickBeauchamp-H thanks. I need to read up on that more. We prefer to keep our transitions in CSS, but we may want migrated to that. That said, I don't see a way (at least in that documentation) to 'chain' the animations/events. What I need is for one CSS (or angular animation) to complete, and then change the css class one more time after. Am I missing that in the documentation?

Comment: You can apply style during the transition, it's explained in the next page of the documentation [Transitions and triggers](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers). However, it doesn't allow you to apply class, only style.

Comment: In your case, you can have two states: `open` and `closed`. In closed, you apply `display: 'none'`. Then you define the transition between open => closed to animate and apply style from your `isClosed` class. If it's possible, I suggest simply using `*ngIf` on the div, it's a bit easier to animate with predefined `:enter` and `:leave` transition.

Comment: @YannickBeauchamp-H the catch is I need 3 states. "start" "in-transition" and "after-transition-is-done".

Comment: You can define style when going from one state to another for the "in-transition". You can even have as many state as you want with different transition between them.